# Dojo Lightbox Close Button

Tags: lightbox, dojo

I have Dojo 1.4, and the lightbox is working.  But the close button doesnt work with IE, I can see it, just not click it.

With Firefox it workes all ok. So I assume the code and css are all ok.

Any ideas?
Greg

Comment: I suggest filing a bug at http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org with an example to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your page?

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .dojoxLightboxText { padding: 0 }
</style>
```